# something strange that PHP working different between safari and chrome?

Tags: php, browser, safari

I have wrote two simple PHP scripts to describe this strange thing.

script A：

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['first']=5;
print_r($_SESSION['first']);
?>
```

script B:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['first']);
$_SESSION['first']=0;
?>
```

If you link to script A at first and then link to script B, I think the result is 5.
And i test in chrome,It is 5 indeed.
But incredible, In safari, the result is 0.
It is like the script B runs reversed, Why? who can help me?

Comment: Cookies are enabled in all browsers? I think safari have them turned off, and then the session is lost

Comment: Cookies are enabled in all browsers.And if i delete "$_SESSION['first']=0;" in script B,It's result will be 5.So the session seems haven't lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried recreating your examples, but what you describe does not happen.

Here are my examples:

http://dianthos.net/stack/22270205/a.php

open it first. It will show "5". Then click on the link for going to the second script. 
(I have added one more line to further indicate what is happening).

Can you confirm that this happens when you open my scripts from chrome and safari as well?

The only case where I have found it showing first 0 in the b script is if you open it without opening the script A first.

Comment: emm...I'm sorry about that,I used another macbook and it works.I found there is something wrong in my safari,And it will link to a php for twice...So that's what happened...Thank you very much~